# Cordova plugin, with native storyboard UI

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am in the midst of creating a Cordova camera plugin. I know there are many alternatives out there, but none of them have all of the functionality that I am looking for, or they are outdated.

So I have been working with the AVCam-iOSUsingAVFoundationtoCaptureImagesandMovies project that Apple provides to get you started with their AVFoundation library.

After working with the library a bit, I realized that I wanted to make it into a Cordova plugin, but the only thing that I am concerned about is the UI functionality of the plugin. So I am wondering if it is possible to include the storyboard files (that render the view / buttons) in the Plugin, so that they work seamlessly, or if it needs to be programmatically created, like other Camera plugins (like CameraPreview) do.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can add a storyboard to a plugin.

First add the storyboard in the plugin.xml

```
<resource-file src="src/ios/YourStoryboard.storyboard"/>
```

Then in the code you can get the initial view controller like this:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: will you give storyboard identifier?? in the above code

Comment: Don't understand the question

Comment: for that particular storyboard we have one ViewController and corresponding class file right! How you will call that cocoa touch class when the storyboard gets loaded